# Как правильно сохранить значения?

Tags: php

Всем здравствуйте, скажите вот сейчас я получаю данные так

```
<?php
//тут я получаю данные, и потом создаю <input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = '$id' />
?>

  <td>$name<input type = 'hidden' name = 'name' value = '$name' /></td>
 <td>$price<input type = 'hidden' name = 'price' value = '$price' /></td>
 <td>$percent%</td>
 <td>$balance</td>
 <td>$count<input type = 'hidden' name = 'count' value = '$count' /></td>
```

Так вот, я посмотрел что в Опере данные в этих полях можно менять, да и вообще это все заметно, но на других сайтах я такого не замечал, так где хранят данные?

Вот к примеру, у меня есть товар который можно купить за цену 120 рублей. Если я все это сохраню в input'e то в Опере заменили значение на 0, и купили товар за 0 рублей, вот пример этой проблемы. Как исправить это?

Comment: Пользователю Вы просто выводите цену для просмотра, зачем давать возможность ее изменять?  
В новый заказ отправляете ИД товара, а потом уже на сервере извлекаете цену из базы данных.

Comment: pfff. 0 это цветочки, -100500, вот это беда :)

По сабжу - пользователь покупает какой-то товар с определенным id, цену этого товара, на моменте покупки, вы смотрите в БД, да, я подменяю кэпа.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать сессии или базу данных